# Induced Representations from Tensor Product of Modules

Tags: modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

In Chapter 7 of J P Serre's book on Representation Theory, he defines a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module as $W'= \mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]}W$
and claims it to be the $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module obtained from $W$ by scalar extension from $\mathbb{C}[H]$ to $\mathbb{C}[G]$.
This definition is used to define Induced Representation later on.

I started reading Serre with a basic knowledge of Group Theory only. I know the definition and properties of FG-modules, but not modules over rings and tensor product of them.

Can anybody clarify me what is happening here, and how to interpret this definition to understand Induced Representations?

Comment: First learn about tensor products of modules over commutative rings and why examples like $\mathbf C \otimes_{\mathbf R} V$ for a real vector space $V$ or ${\mathbf Z}[i] \otimes_{\mathbf Z} A$ for an abelian group (a $\mathbf Z$-module) $A$ are called base extensions that create a complex vector space and a $\mathbf Z[i]$-module, respectively.  Then move on to read about tensor products of suitable modules over a noncommutative ring, which is more subtle than the commutative case.

Comment: @KCd Thank you. Will do that for sure. Can you just explain how to read that expression to understand the motivation behind such definition?

Comment: What do you mean by "read that expression"?